# Making a dropdown in jsp from a resultset in a servlet

Tags: html, sql, jsp, servlets, html-select

My problem is that this dropdown cant be made, cause of a SQL exception

My SQL statement in the servlet looks like this:

```
ResultSet banks = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DTU06.BANKS");
```

And my dropdown is created in JSP file like this

```
<%  ResultSet banks = (ResultSet) request.getAttribute("banks"); %>
<select id="aNum" name="bank">
<%  while (banks.next()) {  %>
    <option value="${banks.getString(2)}">
        <%=banks.getString(1)%>
    </option>
<%  }   %>
</select>
```

The error-code i get looks like this:

> DSRA9110E: ResultSet is closed.

Anyone can see the problem ?

*EDIT1 
I tried playing around with the `banks.next()` in the servlet but i decided to delete it.

Comment: Did you close the `ResultSet` in the Servlet code ? Moreover this looks bad , you can set some `List` as attribute .

Comment: What do you mean "close the ResultSet" ?

Comment: ResultSet is not serializable

Answer (score 0):

ResultSet is not serializable. Either implement your own MyResultSet which implements ResultSet and Serializable, or put your resultset into a collection object and pass it into the jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

After 
`ResultSet banks = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DTU06.BANKS");` 
statement traverse Your `ResultSet` i.e `banks.next()` then add to some collection

e.g

```
public ArrayList getResult();
{
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
//get connection here
ResultSet banks = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DTU06.BANKS");
while(banks.next()){
list.add(banks.getString("columnIndex"));
}
return list
}
```

Call this method then iterate through ArrayList and get when ever you want value i.e `list.get("index")`